# APN settings in Java ME

Tags: java-me, access-point

Since it is not possible to specify the [APN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) for HttpConnection in plain Java ME, are there  vendor specific hacks *other* than BlackBerry OS URL suffixes?

Comment: are you asking about Blackberry specific hacks? if not, what device are you interested to know about?

Comment: I'm interested any Java ME device that does not come from RIM

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is using a suffix:

```
"http://somenonexistingurl.fake;apn=<myapn>"
```

I think it should also work in a J2ME MIDlet running on BB.

As for the other non-bb devices, my guess is no. In J2ME you are not programming to a "phone" but to a "connected limited device" which may not have internet at all.