# Enable 3G and WiFi Simultaneously

Tags: android, networking, wifi, vpn, 3g

Does anyone know if its possible (programatically) to enable both 3G and WiFi to be used simultaneously, both receiving and sending packets?

I have seen various other questions on here, but with the Tethering ability inside Android now, I was wondering if this is a possibility? This has to be on a standard/stock device, and no modifications via root to the OS.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is, as soon as wifi is turned on, 3g will automatically disconnect. As far as I know there is no way round it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve this is by using a APN name with the `HttpConnection`. This is possible in Java ME, Please visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8183599/996493), however i have never tried it.

You need to check for the active connection, if not active first one the switch to the next connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void shutup(){
    SuDroid cmd = new SuDroid();
    cmd.sh.runWaitFor("svc wifi enable");
    cmd.sh.runWaitFor("svc data enable");
    cmd.sh.runWaitFor("svc data prefer");
}
```

Using [SuDroido](https://github.com/LuizCarvalho/SuDroid)